# How to add only necessary icons from libraries? Webpack

Tags: webpack

I use antd lib and I discovered what icons occupy 1/3 my main chunk.

I want to add only necessary icons and try to use `ContextReplacementPlugin`:

```
new ContextReplacementPlugin(/@ant-design[/\\]icons[/\\]lib[/\\]dist$/, /ReloadOutline/), // example
```

However this does not work.

[image]

This is dist.
I think need export es5 transform to es6 for right tree shaking

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it is not actually (in ant@4+ this problem is solved), but I want to show my solution anyways.

Just need to add the follow code in the webpack.config

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '@ant-design/icons/lib/dist$': path.resolve(__dirname, './PATH/icons.js'),
  },
  ...
},
```

and need to create `icon.js`, then to add the needed icons, for example:

```
export { default as UpOutline } from '@ant-design/icons/lib/outline/UpOutline';
```

Answer (score 0):

The [FAQ section of the Ant Design website](https://ant.design/docs/react/faq#I-just-want-to-use-Menu/Button(etc.),-but-it-seems-that-I-have-to-import-the-whole-of-antd-and-its-style) has this to say (I'm pretty sure it applies to the icons, too):

**I just want to use Menu/Button(etc.), but it seems that I have to import the whole of antd and its style.**

Try [babel-plugin-import](https://github.com/ant-design/babel-plugin-import), or import what you need in this way:

```
import Menu from 'antd/es/menu';
import 'antd/es/menu/style/css';
```

or (ES6 way with tree shaking):

```
import { Menu, Breadcrumb, Icon } from 'antd';
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, tree shaking does not shake unnecessary icons, all icons was saved. I think need export es5 (dist) transform to es6 for right tree shaking. Tree shaking works fine without babel-plugin-import and @ant-design/icons/lib/dist - residue of antd.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack will tree-shake only es modules. Additionally you need to define `sideEffects: false` in your package.json.

Be aware that if you use Babel and `@babel/preset-env` you will need to set `modules: false` there too otherwise it will transform es modules to Common JS.